# Is it possible to change the difficulty mid game?

Tags: gnomoria

If I start off on peaceful, can I get mobs to spawn later if I want them to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since 0.8.24 you can change the difficulty from peaceful to normal in the "Kingdom" Menu while playing (first button on the top).

[image: SCreenshot of button]

Patch Notes:
http://forums.gnomoria.com/index.php?topic=2818.0

Comment: It's good to know that it's possible, but I still cannot find the option. What am I missing?

Comment: @oKtosiTe I updated the answer to reflect the location of the button to change the difficulty.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm pretty new to this game, but it would've cost me some effort to locate that. Thanks for updating; upvote added.